# Why am I getting this syntax-error while trying to update a attribute using mysql-query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to update 'pwd' column of 'Goal' table using following mysql query but sad thing is it gives error.  mysql query:

```
UPDATE Goal 
   SET pwd = (SELECT MD5(CONCAT(ID, LEFT(phone,3), '$=')) 
                FROM Esubmission);
```

error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Esubmission)' at line 1

My tables are like below;

```
Esubmission
ID        | pnone       | email            |
--------------------------------------------
20378     | 00000000000 | someone@gmail.com|
20379     | 00000000000 | someone@gmail.com|
20380     | 00000000000 | someone@gmail.com|

Goal
usr   | pwd | time|
--------------------
20378 |     |12:09|
20379 |     |15:29|
20380 |     |15:47|
```

Comment: Does `Esubmission` hold more than one record?  If so, that would be a problem...

Comment: Just wondering, is the ';' required at the end?

Comment: Maybe you need to select it like `SET pwd = (SELECT MD5(...) AS md5 FROM Esubmission)`;

Comment: @omg-ponies yes, there are phone, id, location etc.
@Babiker No I tried without ';', didn't work..

Comment: @chustar still 1064 error.. :(

Comment: As OMG Ponies said if your subquery returns more than 1 row, the update fails.

Comment: An easy fix - to append `LIMIT 1` : `FROM  Esubmission LIMIT 1) `. I'm not sure if it's what you want - it will assign the same value to all `pwd` fields in pwd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.... I'm thinking that you really want to set the password for each user (I think), in which case you'll need to have a join for the update, and that way you can eliminate your multiple values you are selecting.. because the way you have it, you're updating all the values in the Goal table for pwd to the same value... the way below, you update each users pwd to be based on the row joined with the ID. Assuming you have one row for each usr in the esubmission table, this should work:

```
UPDATE Goal    
SET pwd = MD5(CONCAT(ID, LEFT(e.phone,3), '$='))                 
FROM Goal g, Esubmission e
where e.ID = g.usr
```

Comment: I still get error. and I also tried like _UPDATE Goal    
SET pwd = MD5(CONCAT(g.usr, LEFT(g.phone,3), '$='))                 
FROM Goal g_ to generated md5 hash using Goal table itself.

Comment: Is it because the ID field is numeric? the CONCAT functions I believe requires all string....(even though it is supposed to implicitly cast it)

Comment: Also, you don't need 'FROM goal' in the test you tried: in order to do just what you tried, it would be: UPDATE Goal SET pwd = MD5(CONCAT(g.usr, LEFT(g.phone,3), '$='))

Answer (score 0):

I tested it here and worked fine. MySQL 5.1.37

Comment: mine is V. 5.1.54, can you please explain me how u actually did it?

Comment: @Himalay : He probably has just 1(or 0) row in ` Esubmission` table

Comment: If i try to update pwd from same table informations like this : _UPDATE Goal SET pwd = (SELECT MD5(CONCAT(ID, '$=')) FROM Goal);_ I still get error!!! :(